# Error when trying to display ads using Admob

Tags: android, admob

I am using Admob to display ads in my android application but it gives me error code 0 when trying to request for ads. 
In my Admob account it gives me warning :
Your ad units aren't serving ads because your payment information is missing. Add your payment information now. But when i try to add payment information , the page is not opening :
[Admob payment page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrJOj.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I've got the same problem :( Is anybody fixed it?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem by adding a payment information to the Adsense account.